# Alembic drops and creates foreign key constraints (autogenerate) when the table has different schema than the referenced columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, alembic

I am trying to use the autogenerate feature from alembic to update the schema of a MSSQL database.

```python
class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table1"
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint("ID", name="PK_Table1"),
    )

    ID = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

class Table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table2"
    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(['Table1ID'], ['Table1.ID'], name='fk_Table2_Table1')
        {'schema': 'foo'}
    )

    Table1ID = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    Table1_ = relationship('Table1', back_populates='Table2')
```

After executing the command `alembic revision --autogenerate`, this is the `upgrade()` function I get:

```python
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_constraint('fk_Table2_Table1', 'Table2', schema='foo', type_='foreignkey')
    op.create_foreign_key('fk_Table2_Table1', 'Table2', 'Table1', ['Table1ID'], ['ID'], source_schema='foo')
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

After digging into the code, I found that when alembic compares the foreign keys between the schema and the model in the code, sqlalchemy forces a `dbo` schema to the Table1.ID referenced column:

Database foreign key:
('foo', 'Table2', ('Table1ID',), 'dbo', 'Table1', ('ID',), None, None, 'not deferrable')

Model foreign key:
('foo', 'Table2', ('Table1ID',), None, 'Table1', ('ID',), None, None, 'not deferrable')

This difference leads to the drop and create commands in the `upgrade()` function later on. If I remove the `{'schema': 'foo'}` in `__table_args__` the issue disappears so my guess is that the table schema (different from the default one) forces the schema on the foreign key reference.

I would like to know if there is any way to overcome this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I'm also facing this issue. And no luck finding the answer. For now i just edit the alembic generated code and do the db upgrade. But it's very annoying repeated thing especially when the tables grow up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33076699)